# Rails: Better way to access the production.log file when deployed on VPS?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2, production-environment

I have deployed my app on `Linode VPS` and the only way I know to access the `production.log` file is by `ssh-ing` into the console, going to the `production.log` file and opening it by `nano` or `vim` inside the console.

This is very annoying and tedious to read. It normally shows the first line of the log, so in order to see an error I have to keep scrolling down with the down key which is a painfully slow process. How can I open this log outside the console?

Also, does the log file size get ridiculously big if I don't delete its content from time to time?

Comment: I'm not sure to the first part of your question, but to avoid constant scrolling down use [tail](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_%28Unix%29)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`tail` and `grep` can be very helpful for finding things in your logs

however for errors you should use a service, such as airbrake (there are others)

you can try the free developer account, 1 project only - https://signup.airbrake.io/account/new?dev=true

- click the very small 'Signup' link near the bottom

> Or choose the Free plan (1 Project, 1 User, 2 Rate Limit) Signup

yes - periodically you will want to clear your log files - `cat /dev/null > /somewhere/app/shared/log/production.log`

Answer (score 3):

Try `tail -f log/production.log`, it will show your log updating in realtime.

By the way, debug with production log is strange application of this log. I use [errbit](https://github.com/errbit/errbit) for these purposes, it catches errors and shows it is pleasant and usable way.